# C++ SFML анимация

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Всем привет. У меня задание разработать движение электрона во круг атома, это должно быть как анимация. Использовал я для этого библиотеку SFML. Я вроде как реализовал, но в какой-то момент электрон уходит за экран. Потом еще я не знаю как реализовать так что бы объекта(электрон) не было видно когда он за атомом. Заранее спасибо.

Я использовал такую формулу для движения по окружности

```
x = x0 + radius*sin(angle);
y = y0 + radius*cos(angle);
alpha += deltaTime * k;
```

где x0 и у0 - это координаты центра; х, у - координаты объекта, а alpha - угол.

```
alpha += deltaTime * k
```

это изменение угла со временем.

Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
   float xo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)
   float yo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)

   float radius = 10;//радиус

   float k = 0.0f;//время(time)

   float x = 130;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)
   float y = 330;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)

   float rotation = 5.0;

   //float x = 1000 / 2;
   //float y = 1000 / 2;

   float alpha = 0;//угол(angle)

   float speed = 2000.0f;

   RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Atom");
   window.setFramerateLimit(60);

   Clock clock;
   sf::Event windowEvent;

   Texture herotexture;
   herotexture.loadFromFile("atom_image.png");

   Sprite herosprite;
   herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);
//herosprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 99, 48, 51));//получили нужный нам прямоугольник с котом
   herosprite.setPosition(250, 250); //выводим спрайт в позицию x y (output the sprite to the position x y)

   CircleShape circle;
   circle.setRadius(radius);
   circle.setOutlineColor(Color::Red);
   circle.setOutlineThickness(5);
   circle.setPosition(x, y);
   circle.setRotation(0);

   while (window.isOpen())
   {
       Event event;
       while (window.pollEvent(event))
       {
           if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
               window.close();
       }

      //circle.rotate(rotation);

      //alpha = (float)clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds() * k;
      clock.restart();
      k = k / 800;
      float deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();

      alpha += deltaTime*(float)clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

      float Radius = (float)herosprite.getPosition().x - (float)circle.getPosition().x;

      cout << "\nGet Position Atom is -> " << (float)herosprite.getPosition().x << endl;
      cout << "\nGet Position Circle is -> " << (float)circle.getPosition().x << endl;
      cout << "\nRadius is -> " << Radius << endl;

      x = xo + Radius*sin(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)
      y = yo + Radius*cos(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)

      Vector2f direction(x, y);

      circle.move(direction * deltaTime * speed);
      //circle.move(direction);
      //circle.move(x, y);

      window.clear();
      window.draw(herosprite);
      window.draw(circle);
      window.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: При определённом значении `alpha` (когда электрон начинает заходить за ядро, подберите значение опытным путём) вам необходимо отрисовывать объекты в обратном порядке. Как только электрон полностью выйдет из-за ядра (соответствующее значение `alpha` тоже подберите опытным путём) вернитесь к обычному порядку отрисовки.

Comment: Иными словами, `window.clear(); if(alpha > XXX && alpha < YYY)
 {window.draw(circle); window.draw(herosprite);} else {window.draw(herosprite); window.draw(circle);} window.display();`

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно проверять координаты электрона и атома, и когда они примерно совпадают, то рисовать сначала электрон, а затем атом или же не рисовать электрон вовсе.
Например:

```
if( 
      !herosprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects( circle.getGlobalBounds() ) 
  ||  circle.getPosition().x <herosprite.getPosition().x
)
draw(circle);
```